# How to map LocalDate to Date using Dozer or ModelMapper?

Tags: java, dozer, modelmapper

How to properly setup mapping of either Dozer 6.4.1 or ModelMapper 2.2.0 to successfuly map `java.time.LocalDate` field to `java.util.Date` field and vice versa?

Consider these classes:

```
public class Foo {
    private LocalDate signatureDate;
    // getters and setters
}

public class Bar {
    private Date signatureDate;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Then calling `mapper.map(fooInstance, Bar.class);` won't work.

I've tried creating and registering custom converters. Using Dozer, I created class `LocalDateToDateConverter` that extends `DozerConverter<LocalDate, Date>` and implemented correct conversion. Then registered it like this:

```
mapper = DozerBeanMapperBuilder
        .create()
        .withCustomConverter(new LocalDateToDateConverter())
        .build();
```

but the `com.github.dozermapper.core.converters.DateConverter` is used instead when it comes to converting the class.

Also it's worth noting, that I would like a generic solution for all classes that may need this type conversion, so that I don't have to make converter for each class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using model mapper you can configure [converters](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/converters/) between `Date` and `LocalDate` for `Bar` and `Foo` classes.

Converters:

```
private static final Converter<Date, LocalDate> DATE_TO_LOCAL_DATE_CONVERTER = mappingContext -> {
    Date source = mappingContext.getSource();
    return source.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
};

private static final Converter<LocalDate, Date> LOCAL_DATE_TO_DATE_CONVERTER = mappingContext -> {
    LocalDate source = mappingContext.getSource();
    return Date.from(source.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
};
```

Mapper configuration:

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();

TypeMap<Bar, Foo> barToFooMapping = mapper.createTypeMap(Bar.class, Foo.class);
barToFooMapping.addMappings(mapping -> mapping.using(DATE_TO_LOCAL_DATE_CONVERTER).map(Bar::getSignatureDate, Foo::setSignatureDate));
TypeMap<Foo, Bar> fooToBarMapping = mapper.createTypeMap(Foo.class, Bar.class);
fooToBarMapping.addMappings(mapping -> mapping.using(LOCAL_DATE_TO_DATE_CONVERTER).map(Foo::getSignatureDate, Bar::setSignatureDate));
```

Please pay attention to the timezones while converting `Date` to `LocalDate` and `LocalDate` to `Date`.